# How would a person work his way to being a Kingpin of a city or country?

Tags: society, economy, cities, civilization, medieval

I am making a fantasy story where a guy who starts from the bottom eventually becomes top-dog of the entire area through his own efforts.

Let's say a charming and highly intelligent modern person (a genius) gets dropped in a medieval fantasy world.

Besides humans, monsters also exist in this world, but they are brutish and will kill any and all outsiders. The man in question has good intentions, but he'll play dirty if he must (kind of like a Machiavellian guy or Lex Luthor from comics).

Comment: Interesting question, but I cannot see how this is about worldbuilding. Your world is given and you are asking about the story in it.

Comment: The area is about one hundred times too small for the given contents. 2500 ha is 25 square kilometers, or a square with a side of 5 km (3 miles); it can feed less than one thousand people and their animals. (Medieval agriculture did not use artificial fertilizers, people need some wood, sheep etc.) That's an estate with one or two villages, not a county with two towns, a capital city, a king, and a band of rebel monsters.

Comment: I edited my posts

Comment: If you want your question to be reopened, edit it to no longer be story based. Once the question is on topic people will vote to reopen it. Please don't re-ask the same question in another post.

Answer (score 2):

In such a situation the rule of thumb for surviving is: "*show you are worth more alive than dead*".

It follows that, carrying on that much money, he has to prove having really important skills for not being killed and robbed (not necessarily in this order).

Being charming is not enough to be spared, and to be valuable to monsters is even harder. The best bet is probably to show great medical or weapon forging skills. Something like he heals a seriously sick monster/citizen, or he makes a weapon using which a flimsy person like him can kill a strong monster/citizen.

Once he has established some sort of value for his person, he can start building a network of contacts and interests in the city, grabbing opportunities as they arise. If you have ever played GTA, you know how it goes.

Comment: I edited my posts

Answer (score -2):

He can go to a first merchant he sees in the city
Hello - he says - do you have any ques... I mean jobs?

Or go to seeks some gossips, employ some mercenaries, equip them with upgraded weapons and armours and then send them to pacify those rebels. Then he goes "bla bla bla your king is useless, I'm better, off with his head"

And voila. he became a king himself.

Comment: I edited my post